# Joining multiple event handlers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to join multiple event handlers in Javascript as in the following scenario :

```
onClick="doSomething();" onKeyUp="doSomething();" onLoad="doSomething();"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function doSomething(){ console.log("Done!"); }
var element = document.getElementById("my-element");
element.onClick = element.onKeyUp = element.onLoad = doSomething;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a javascript library's code to add events to abstract browser differences away from yourself.

I also suggest passing the event itself to the function(both prototype and jquery do this).

```
<script>
function doSomething(event){
  /*your code here*/
  /*this refers to the dom node in both libraries*/
};
</script>
```

[JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind#typedatafn)

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script>
  $("my-element").bind("click keyup load", doSomething);
</script>
```

[Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe)

```
<script src="http://www.prototypejs.org/assets/2008/9/29/prototype-1.6.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
  $('my-element').observe('click', doSomething);
  $('my-element').observe('keyup ', doSomething);
  $('my-element').observe('load', doSomething);
</script>
```